# Dynamically changing content of UIScrollView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a menu for a local multi-player game that dynamically updates when peers become available on the network.

The interface I want to implement is a `UIScrollView`, where each page displays information about a peer. Ideally, these pages are added and removed when a peer's availability changes.

I have looked through several tutorials using `UIScrollView`, but they all seem to pull page information from a plist or pre-loaded array.

What I want must be possible; weather app behaves in a similar manner, dynamically adding or deleting location pages. I'm not sure where to turn for further help, though. How do I dynamically update my scroll view's contents as outside events occur?

Comment: Either you have to alloc & reload your UIScrollView adding Pages each time whenever a new user gets online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with UICollectionView instead, it seems to provide a better method of implementation for what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this [Ray Wenderlich Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content).

I've used it as a basis for doing a paged scroll and the mechanism is simple enough to extend to whatever dynamic scheme you would like.

Answer (score -1):

You can check this site for Multiple Tutorials & examples for UIScrollview. The link:

[is Here..](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=scrollview)

I am sure, you'll able to find some good code for your need. Hope it works for you.